# Text and image slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, json

I have found this http://fiddle.jshell.net/KFmLv/5750/

I want to load the content (image & text) directly from a json file using the  prev and next buttons.

How could I do this?

Comment: There is no images in your JsFiddle. What have you tried for the moment ?

Answer (score 0):

To load json, use [getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) method, something like

```
$.getJSON("data.json", function(data) { doSomething(); } )
```

I'm not sure what kind of effect you want to achieve, but maybe it would be something like

```
$("#next").click(function() {
    $("#img").src = images[++current];
    $("#info").text( texts[current] );
})
```